# How to exclude a path from authentication in a spring based reactive application?

Tags: spring, security, reactor

In a non reactive spring application I would usually create a configuration class, extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and configure the `WebSecurity` like such:

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/pathToIgnore");
}
```

How can I do the equivalent in a reactive application?

Comment: You need to return a `SecurityWebFilterChain` bean with the respective configuration that's needed. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-reactive

Comment: Check out the config here https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-5-reactive-security/src/main/java/com/baeldung/reactive/security/SecurityConfig.java

Comment: Did this help you @jimonthebarn?

Comment: @MadhuBhat The examples given only illustrate how the 'authorization' aspect of the security chain is configured. E.g. If a certain resource needs some special role (like `.pathMatchers("/", "/admin").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")`) or if a certain resource has no additional permissions required (`.anyExchange().permitAll()`) This does however not affect if 'authentication' is attempted on a given path or not (e.g. it will try to authenticate the caller even on paths where access is permitted without having a certain role, authority).

Comment: What you need to configure there is `http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/pathToIgnore").permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated().and().formLogin().build()`. This will make sure that paths matched by pathMatchers will be permitted without auth and any other paths will be authenticated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your security config class which you have annotated with `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` and `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity`, register a bean as follows:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/pathToIgnore")
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .build();
}
```

In this config, `pathMatchers("/pathToIgnore").permitAll()` would configure it to allow the paths matched to be excluded from auth and `anyExchange().authenticated()` would configure it to authenticate all other requests.

Comment: @jimonthebarn did this help you? Please let me know otherwise.

Comment: The underlying issue was something different and therefore the question should have been phrased differently. But your answer is valid for the question at hand.

Comment: What was the underlying issue @jimonthebarn?

Comment: I was implementing the authentication by making use of a custom `ServerSecurityContextRepository`. It exposes methods for loading and saving a `SecurityContext`. In the case of the load I was extracting the authorisation header, parsing the contained token and verifying its permissions. This happens  on every request regardless of the actual required permission on a path (this is where my assumptions were wrong). In case of a call to a unprotected endpoint I did not send the auth header (which is my expected behaviour) and that lead to exception and consequently to the request being denied.

Comment: Can't get that solution to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478586/how-to-exclude-actuator-from-securitywebfilterchain-authorization

Comment: If you ignore this way, when you hit `/pathToIgnore` the security filter still get triggered, thus a waste of time. We should configure using  `NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher` to completely ignore the filter when the user visit `/pathToIgnore`