# How to extend the Security configuration provided by oauth2 resource server in a reactive web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm building a spring-boot 2.4 app using WebFlux. This application is using the oauth2 resource server extension provided by spring-security. However I need to exclude port 8081 as this runs actuator internally and should not be protected by oauth2.

I'm using the spring-boot starter to configure the resource-server, so the creation of the SecurityWebFilterChain is not in my code and I just want to add to the behavior, not create everything anew.

With WebMVC that was straight forward as:

```java
@Configuration
class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity http) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work any more with WebFlux (or am I just doing s.th. wrong?). I wasn't able to find a similar approach. Only the hint that it would be possible to create multiple `SecurityWebFilterChain`s. However as the resource server autoconfiguration only creates the FilterChain on an `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(SecurityWebFilterChain.class)`, it will not create one, if I create one for the exceptional case.

Any hints on how this is *intended* to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web ignoring using spring-webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740163/web-ignoring-using-spring-webflux)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, but it basically only summarizes what I already found. I edited my question to point out the in my case the issue is that I have a `SecurityWebFilterChain` already created in a library, which I would only want to extend instead of replace.