# Spring security: avoid authorization and authentication for certain paths

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

This is my related spring security configuration:

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http,
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter
    ) {
        return http
            .httpBasic(HttpBasicSpec::disable)
            .csrf(CsrfSpec::disable)
            .formLogin(FormLoginSpec::disable)
            .anonymous(AnonymousSpec::disable)
            .logout(LogoutSpec::disable)
            .authorizeExchange((authorize) -> authorize
                .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/login/**");
    }
```

As you can see, I'm setting an `AuthenticationWebFilter` at `SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION` level.

I'm also avoiding to authorize `"/actuator/**"` and `"/login/**"` paths and I'm avoiding authentication for using `WebSecurityCustomizer`.

However, when I'm trying to reach above paths, I see authentication process is launched for above paths since, `authenticationFilter` is reached at code.

How could avoid authorization and authentication only for `"/actuator/**"` and `"/login/**"`?

**EDIT:**

I've took a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740163/web-ignoring-using-spring-webflux), but its approach is what I'm using exactly with `WebSecurityCustomizer`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web ignoring using spring-webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740163/web-ignoring-using-spring-webflux)

Comment: Above question recommends using `WebSecurityCustomizer`. It's what I'm using. I think my configuration is so explicit, ignore `"/actuator/**"` and `/login/**`. I don't quite figure out why not it just works...

Comment: The answer in the question above does not use the `WebSecurityCustomizer`. The `WebSecurityCustomizer` is for servlet applications. The answer uses `securityMatcher` with a `NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher`.

Comment: ok... I'll dig a bit more. I thought resource server always needs an authorization server to verify tokens... I guess using "our" approach actions like "revoke tokens" are not possible...

Comment: @Jordi So what is the solution? I want to exclude the `actuator` and have a similar issue.