# How to bypass some urls in spring webflux security?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring webflux application and has enabled spring webflux security using below code:-

```
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    log.debug("Configuring tenant web security");
    return http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .addFilterAt(authorizationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
        .build();
  }

  private AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter() {
    AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(
        customAuthenticationManager);
    authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(customAuthenticationConverter);
    return authenticationWebFilter;
  }

  private AuthorizationWebFilter authorizationWebFilter() {
    return new AuthorizationWebFilter(customAuthorizationManager);
  }
```

I want to bypass the actuator urls mentioned in code but somehow they are still getting in `ServerAuthenticationConverter` class which I have overriden to parse the headers.

I am making request for `localhost:8082/actuator/health` and it is still going through all the security chain.

What am I doing wrong in here?

This below link is related to this issue but couldn't find any helpful answers:-
[How to exclude a path from authentication in a spring based reactive application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178552/how-to-exclude-a-path-from-authentication-in-a-spring-based-reactive-application)

Debug logs with exception:-

```
2021-05-27 21:11:50.496 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
2021-05-27 21:11:50.497 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] i.n.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory     : Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@1afad0f4
2021-05-27 21:11:50.510 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xdbf63e0b, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53830] New http connection, requesting read
2021-05-27 21:11:50.510 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x3302bee3, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53829] New http connection, requesting read
2021-05-27 21:11:50.510 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig  : [id: 0x3302bee3, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53829] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2021-05-27 21:11:50.510 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig  : [id: 0xdbf63e0b, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53830] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2021-05-27 21:11:50.516 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
2021-05-27 21:11:50.516 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2021-05-27 21:11:50.516 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2021-05-27 21:11:50.516 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2021-05-27 21:11:50.516 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.delayedQueue.ratio: 8
2021-05-27 21:11:50.542 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xdbf63e0b, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53830] Increasing pending responses, now 1
2021-05-27 21:11:50.547 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [id: 0xdbf63e0b, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53830] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@60ba6618
2021-05-27 21:11:50.553 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [dbf63e0b-1] HTTP GET "/actuator/health"
2021-05-27 21:11:50.589  WARN 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.r.c.a.c.e.RestWebExceptionHandler      : Web request for uri http://localhost:8082/actuator/health failed with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: X-Auth header is not present.
    at com.demo.ceresgateway.app.config.security.CustomServerAuthenticationConverter.resolveHeaders(CustomServerAuthenticationConverter.java:61)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/actuator/health" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at com.demo.ceresgateway.app.config.security.CustomServerAuthenticationConverter.resolveHeaders(CustomServerAuthenticationConverter.java:61)
        at com.demo.ceresgateway.app.config.security.CustomServerAuthenticationConverter.convert(CustomServerAuthenticationConverter.java:31)
        at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.lambda$filter$2(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:112)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2346)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1784)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:128)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:360)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollectList.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:81)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:301)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:140)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:270)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:200)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:173)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer$HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServer.java:632)
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:612)
        at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport$ChildObserver.onStateChange(ServerTransport.java:453)
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:510)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:208)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

2021-05-27 21:11:50.595 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [dbf63e0b-1] Resolved [IllegalArgumentException: Only one of (X-Auth-Token) or (X-Username, X-Api-Key/X-Password) headers should be present at a time and when giving X-Username only one of X-Api-Key or X-Password header should be present.] for HTTP GET /actuator/health
2021-05-27 21:11:50.611 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [dbf63e0b-1] Encoding [{timestamp=Thu May 27 21:11:50 IST 2021, path=/actuator/health, status=400, message=Only one of (X-A (truncated)...]
2021-05-27 21:11:50.656 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xdbf63e0b, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53830] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
2021-05-27 21:11:50.660 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xdbf63e0b, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53830] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel
2021-05-27 21:11:50.660 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [dbf63e0b-1] Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
2021-05-27 21:11:50.662 DEBUG 87018 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xdbf63e0b, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8082 - R:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:53830] Last HTTP response frame
```

Comment: Update your question with spring security server debug logs and what request you are making.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Can’t see any debug logs.

Comment: Updated the debug logs

Comment: Disabling security as you have done means that some of springs internal filters will be disabled. It does not mean that every filter in the filterchain is disabled. You have built custom filters which means you have opted out of using the functionality that is provided in the framework. My suggestion is that you customize springs built in filters if you want to be able to leverage things like exclusions etc. Your other option is to build in exclusions in your custom filters. Me personally consider custom security filters bad practice. All custom security is bad practice.

Comment: But how does this works in non reactive way by giving like 
```@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/pathToIgnore");
}``` 
Isn't there a way to do this in spring reactive?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Disabling security is extrem bad practice.

Comment: I want to ignore the security on actuator urls and let it pass through

Comment: Well you have already opted out to using the framework bu applying custom filters, so you then need to apply exceptions in your filters. Webflux security is not like servlet security.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add the `AuthenticationWebFilter` and `AuthorizationWebFilter` manually in your configuration.

A more modern way to achieve what you want is usually doing like this:

```java
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeExchange((exchanges) -> exchanges
            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
        )
        .csrf().disable();

    return http.build();
}
```

You can find more information about the security configuration in the [Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-webflux)

Comment: I have added AuthenticationWebFilter and AuthorizationWebFilter to give some custom implementations of those.