# How to exclude actuator from SecurityWebFilterChain authorization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have the `WebSecurityConfiguration` class which uses `SecurityWebFilterChain` to authorize access. Still, I want to exclude `actuator` from it so I have another bean for it but the endpoint still is not accessible w/o authorization.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration 
{
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChainExcludeActuator(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                           ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/actuator/health")))
                   .authorizeExchange()
                   .anyExchange().authenticated()
                   .and()
                   .csrf().disable()
                   .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http)
    {

        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/domains/**", "/address/**").permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .formLogin().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Any thoughts on what I have missed?

PS

Even the simple code below will require to provide authorization when I expect is not required for the `actuator`

```
        http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();

        return http.build();
```

Comment: If Spring Security is on the classpath, then web applications are [secured by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security). Your custom security configuration must [explicitly allow unauthenticated access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.security) to the Actuator endpoints.

Comment: @ChinHuang added a bean from that example but it shows that `securityMatcher` doesn't exist for `HttpSecurity`

Comment: Not sure you can define multiple beans but you need to add `.pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()`

Comment: @Alex I had it before just under the first `pathMatchers()` and did not work out as it still required authorization

Comment: please enable your spring security debug logs and post your logs in full from start up to doing a full request so that we dont have to do guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can allow individual endpoints like this:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .build();
}
```