# How to exclude a swagger path from authentication in Spring web flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, swagger, spring-webflux

i need to exclude swagger path in my spring web flux. But it seems like the securityContextRepository load method still authenticate every calls.

I have added permitAll() to my securityWebFilterChain
[image]

This is my SecurityContextRepository which have custom token checking method.
[image]

So the problem is that the it will still goes into the "load" function in the securityContextRepository to check the token despite i have added the permitAll() for my path. This will cause me unable to load swagger because everything still goes through the load function and do authencation.

I have read [How to exclude a path from authentication in a spring based reactive application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178552/how-to-exclude-a-path-from-authentication-in-a-spring-based-reactive-application)
this thread as it has the similar question as me, but I not sure how the

```
NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher
```

my pom using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.8, and webflux and openapi as below.
[image]

Any kind soul to help me on this? i just started on webflux.